# bodyParser response 'undefined' in node app post method console.log

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am attempting to use middleware to catch the body of a post request, and dynamically use the message ID of the telnyx API endpoint to populate other fields, etc.

Followed the documentation here to a point, several times and cannot get the terminal to output anything but undefined when I send a message to my telnyx number: https://developers.telnyx.com/docs/v2/messaging/quickstarts/receiving-sms-and-mms

I have tried cors thinking that could be the issue from what I read in other posts, and know that express and bodyParser are no longer bundled so I used all both of those as well in an attempt to capture the data. Forgive me if it is obvious.

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const axios = require('axios').default;
const cors = require('cors');
const telnyx = require("telnyx")("MYAPIKEY")

const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded( {extended: true} ));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`New message from ${req.body.from}: ${req.body.body}`);
});

const port = 8080;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App running on port ${port}`));
```

Here are the dependencies:

```js
{
  "name": "telnyxjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "telnyx": "^1.13.1"
  }
}
```

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzHOZ.png)
[ngrok capture of post data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWoWo.png)

Comment: What is the output from ${req.body} ?

Comment: @koodies it is undefined

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but remove `app.use(bodyParser.json());`.  The `express.json()` line of code already does all of this for you.  You do not need body-parser any more as it is already included with Express.

Comment: I thought they were bundled separately, but will do. Thank you @jfriend00

Comment: If `req.body` is empty, then either your request is not sending anything in the body or the content-type is not `application/json` so the middleware doesn't do anything with it or the content isn't valid JSON.  If you show the client-side code, we can perhaps see what might be wrong there.